# How to get background color in Emacs?

Tags: terminal, emacs, gnome-terminal

In Emacs no window mode, the background is automatically the same as the terminal (gnome-terminal). When I look at `(frame-parameters)` I see that `(background-color . "unspecified-bg")`. Well, for me, the background happens to be black. Is there a way to find out what the actual background color is for an Emacs session?

Comment: I don't think that the background color of a terminal emulator can be detected by an application inside of the terminal.

Comment: I do know this information can be found with `gconftool`...

Comment: @Jeff: And that is all you need to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to find out from the terminal, you can use that selfsame command to find out from Emacs.

In my case, I'd make a script like this:

```
#!/bin/zsh

cat .Xresources | grep 'URxvt\*background\:' | cut -d" " -f2
```

(Note: `-d` is to set the field delimiter, `-f` is to set what field is to be shown: the first field is `1`, not `0`)

The command looks the way it does because `.Xresources`, the file that **sets** the background color, looks like this:

```
# ...
URxvt*background: black
# ...
```

Make the script executable (`chmod +x`), and put it in your `PATH` (`echo $PATH`).

If the script is called `what_bg`, in Emacs, `M-x shell-command RET what_bg`.

**Edit** (in response to comment):

See if this works. I tested it from Emacs, and in urxvt, xterm, and rxvt. While it is more portable than the first script, it assumes `.Xresources` configuration (which is, while not uncommon, obviously not everywhere).

I'm starting to wonder, though, why you need this to begin with?

And, if you indeed need it, can't you just **look** on the window to determine its color?

Anyway, the script:

```
#!/bin/zsh

terminal_emulator_parents=`pstree -As $$`
tep_list=`echo $terminal_emulator_parents | tr -s "-" | tr "-" " " \
          | tac -s' ' | tr '\n' ' '`

found="false"
for process in `echo $tep_list`; do
    if [[ $process =~ ("urxvt"|"xterm"|"rxvt") ]]; then # here: add all
        found="true"                                    # terminal emulators
        break                                           # configurable
    fi                                                  # (and *configured*)
done                                                    # in ~/.Xresources

if [[ $found == "true" ]]; then
    echo -n "$process: "
    cat ~/.Xresources | grep -ie ^$process'\*background\:' \
                      | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f2
else
    echo "Couldn't determine the terminal emulator."
fi
```

Comment: I guess this is as close as I'll get for now. I was hoping to find something a little more cross-platform, but this is unix.stackexchange... `shell-command` is new to me so that's a good find.

Comment: @Jeff: Made an edit; take a look.